# Multiple save in model object django

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I use driver cassandra for my db backend in django , here is my problem :

when I wanna run multiple save in a model object instance , the first one save successfully but the others save wont update my record , here is a example :

```
obj = Mymodel.objects.get(id=2)

obj.field1 = 2
obj.save()

obj.field2 = 3
obj.save() # this save don't work
```

am I doying right or for every update i should refresh my model object like this :

```
obj = Mymodel.objects.get(id=obj.id)
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `refresh_from_db` method on `obj` after first save. [Link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database)

```
obj.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: this method is for django orm base :) in cassandra driver has no attribute 'refresh_from_db'